# How does importing React allow JSX to be processed as JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React with create-react-app and I understand how to make components with JSX. For example a simple stateless component is something like:

```
import React from 'react';

const Widget = (props) => <h1>{props.text}</h1>

export default Widget;
```

So importing React uses `createElement()` for the conversion of the HTML-looking JSX (`<h1>{props.text}</h1>`), but how is that function applied? It's not like I am explicitly using React for anything. If there is some kind of compiling go on as the app is built, then why does React need to be imported?

Comment: I see I've been hit a down vote or two here. Is this question too dumb for SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Babel compiles JSX into regular Javascript, then your React import, more accurately `React.createElement` function does the job. Here is the compiled version of your code:

```
"use strict";

var Widget = function Widget(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    "h1",
    null,
    props.text
  );
};
```

Comment: So the import makes sense in the transpiled version! Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can write your code without JSX then you don't need Babel here. As you can see, actually you are using React here.

Answer (score 1):

Importing React doesn't convert JSX into HTML; Babel does that. [Babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/en) is a JavaScript compiler.

Babel effectively turns

```
// Display a "Like" <button>
return (
  <button onClick={() => this.setState({ liked: true })}>
    Like
  </button>
);
```

into

```
// Display a "Like" <button>
return React.createElement(
  'button',
  { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
  'Like'
);
```

Read more in the React docs [Add JSX to a Project](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project).