# import React from 'react' - why this is necessary

Tags: reactjs, import

```
import React from 'react';
```

I have started React recently, but i can't find, what is it and why this is necessary. My first application works without it. Could you give me reference to official source, i can't find it at  https://reactjs.org/

Comment: This might give you some idea about whats going on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import. Its not a react thing, its really more of a javascript thing.

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886682/how-does-importing-react-allow-jsx-to-be-processed-as-js/51886723#51886723 How can you use React without it? How is your app written?

Comment: @devserkan i connected "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js">
"https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"
"https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"                       does it replace import?

Comment: So, you included React, ReactDOM, and Babel as standalone packages to your app. This is one way of using React. But, if you create a react app via npm, you will install those packages locally and import as shown in your question.

Comment: @devserkan Thank you. Could you say too - via npm import will replace all three pacages?

Comment: You are welcome. I've provided an answer, it answers this question, too.

Comment: By the way, `import` is a Javascript **thing**. If you are not so comfortable with Javascript, first study it a little bit more.

Comment: @devserkan i mean, all 3 or not all 3?)) Thanks, i understood.

Comment: I see now :) Also, again no, you will import `React` and `ReactDOM`. Babel  will be configured via a bundler like Webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you explained in your comment is one way of using React. With this simple way, you add the related packages to your HTML file as standalone packages. `React` is being used here to use core functionalities like `React.createElement`, `ReactDOM` for rendering your elements into the DOM, `Babel` for using `JSX`. `Babel` compiles `JSX` into regular `Javascript`. See the link that I gave in my comment to see an example.

Now, the other and more appropriate way of doing this creating your React applications via `npm` or `yarn`.

After creating your project, you must install all those packages again, since you will need them:

```
yarn init
yarn add react react-dom babel *some_babel_packages*
```

After that, you can start to write your app. But, as you write as a learner you will need some **things** that you see other people using like Webpack, dev server, hot reloading, etc. and you will want them. Believe me, you will. Then there is going to be two options for you.

- You will search how you can accomplish those things.
- You will use `create-react-app`

If you want to learn how to set up those things, just Google it. You will find some tutorials but just be sure they are up to date.

If you want to immediately dive into coding with React, use `create-react-app`. Depending on your OS, search a little bit how to install it, then use it like:

```
create-react-app myproject
cd myproject
yarn start
```

Voila! Everything is ready.