# Why do I see JSX and not the compiled code during debugging

Tags: reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I have started learning to react and am stuck at a query but not able to find an answer in this forum.
A related query is present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886682/how-does-importing-react-allow-jsx-to-be-processed-as-js)

**Query:**
Babel compiles the JSX code to React.createElement() but during debugging in chrome developer tools, I see JSX and not the compiled code. How come browser understand JSX syntax here? However, debugging JSX line by line takes me inside React.createElement function.

Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: You can look into or search about source maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. The reason is source maps. I disabled source maps in Chrome Settings and then could see the compiled code. Thanks, Yong Quan for the direction.